# react hook form: as vs render: unable to understrand the syntax and how are they same

Tags: react-hook-form

I have seen in react hook forms using `as` and also `render`

Eg:

```
    <Controller
      render={({ field }) => <input {...field} />}
      name="firstName"
      control={control}
      defaultValue=""
    />
```

or

```
    <Controller
      as={<input .. />}
      name="firstName"
      control={control}
      defaultValue=""
    />
```

whats the difference

Answer (score 1):

`<Controller/>` is good to use with there is an external controlled component such (e.g. Material-UI) to wrap the whole component and control is easier.
`render` is useful when you want to customise the external component while `as` is just renders the original component. An example of using `render` could be:

```
import { TextField } from '@mui/material';
import { Controller } from 'react-hook-form';

const FormTextField = ({
  label,
  name,
  ...props
}) => {
  return (
      <Controller
        name={name}
        render={({ field, fieldState: { error } }) => (
          <TextField
            {...field}
            label={label}
            error={!!error}
            helperText={error ? error?.message : ''}
          />
        )}
        {...props}
      />
  );
};
```

As you can see, `render` gives you ability to access different values (such as error) in the Material UI component which is not easy to do with `as`.

Read more about what properties you have access in `render` at https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller

This example is also helpful: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-v7-controller-5h1q5